# Tomcat 7.0 not getting start from Eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I have installed tomcat 7.0 on my system. When I am trying to run my application on the server from eclipse, it shows me this error

```
The archive: C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/bin/bootstrap.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: that is bootstrap.jar is available at that path

Comment: see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846191/connecting-tomcat-server-to-eclipse

Comment: see if i am http://localhost:8080/ it is working properly but with eclipse it is not running

Comment: @Raúl what he is saying i am not able to understand  that

Answer (score 5):

double-click on Tomcat server -->  click on Overview of Tomcat settings appears --> "Open launch configuration" then Classpath --> under classpath...Edit User Entries here

Comment: this helped me solve my problem. When I told eclipse to download + install Tomcat7, eclipse created a separate folder `Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config`, even though I told it to use `Tomcat 7`. Looks like eclipse downloaded + installed to folder I specified, `Tomcat 7`, yet in the actual server config, eclipse put path `Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config`. So after double-click on Tomcat server -- I had to change the configuration path to the proper path `Tomcat 7`, which had necessary jars, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As your Error shows bootstrap.jar is not in classpath so,

1. Go through eclipse-->Build path--> configure build path check your server .
2. Check the your server lib for given jar
3. If this is not resolve your problem delete your server , install again, and add your server in your new eclipse workspace project.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the server configuration, and configure the server again.

If it doesn't work, change the server directory location.

If still issue, try un & reinstall of Tomcat. As a last option - try Tomcat 6/8 instead of 7.

Comment: every thing what you said i have tried before posting the question

Comment: ha ha ha ..no i haven't tried that will it help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

you have to add class path of java in the environment variable and then add the path of your Tomcat to the PATH.