# Changing Apache's classpath in STS

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, spring-tool-suite

my problem is exactly like this one
[Connecting Tomcat server to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846191/connecting-tomcat-server-to-eclipse). The problem is that once the JARs are edited, STS does not save the changes. Anybody knows which file i have to change in order to do it manually.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see what problem you are referring to by clicking on the URL you provided. It points to the top of the article on developerworks. However, I also don't understand what you mean by "JARs are edited"? Do you edit a JAR file of a library?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I just copied and pasted the right URL.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail? I still don't get it. Sorry for still not understanding the issue. A sample project migth help as well.